# Android giving wrong location

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am using fused api helper to get location,
I get correct location almost 99% of but 1% of the time the variation is huge... more than 1000km with good accuracy as well
how do we rectify this?

Comment: Please post your code please

Answer (score 2):

I also implemented fused api and this happened to me , so i tried LocationListener and got always actual result

Answer (score 0):

Cell tower location might be wrong in database, and because of this, wrong location is returned.

You can refer to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36990166) for more info. Additionally, you can add code in your app to fetch cell tower details & query geolocation API to verify whether the returned result is same or not.